# can't ping between bridged macvlans

Tags: linux, bridge

I have 2 addresses one on eth0 one on eth0.1. eth0.1 was created like this:

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.1 type macvlan
```

dhclient eth0.1 does not get an address, even though eth0.1 does 
even after assigning the IP manually, I cannot ping between eth0 and eth0.1

I tried Brigding:

```
# brctl addbr bridge
# brctl addif eth0 bridge
# brctl addif bridge eth0
# brctl addif bridge eth0.1
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
bridge      8000.080027b37d2f   no  eth0
                            eth0.1
# bridge showmacs bridge
port no mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
 1  08:00:27:b3:7d:2f   yes        0.00
 1  52:54:00:12:35:00   no        44.45
 2  d2:b2:3a:79:9c:2c   yes        0.00
```

still can't ping between them.. What do I do?

edit: can't get an IP from dhclient either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly a trivial omission: Did you do

> ip link set eth0.1 up

after creating it?

Comment: yep ifconfig shows all interfaces up.

Comment: Hm... Some ideas: 1) Skip `brctl addif eth0 bridge`, 2) Change the name from eth0.1 to e.g. eth0mv1 (maybe something doesn't like ifconfig alias-like name connected with macvlan device). 3) Show output of `ip addr show`. 4) How do you test pinging between the interfaces?

Comment: well.. rebooted, tried 1 and 2. something seems to be working.. I'll update after I get some sleep....

Comment: Now I have a new problem but I'll ask it in a separate post. Thanks